# autoref with the float package

Tags: floats, hyperref, cross-referencing, subfloats

I would like to use `\autoref{fig:subfig:a}`, but I don't get the figure number by simply typing this. My code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amstext,amsmath,latexsym,mathtools}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Aya}

\autoref{fig:ABC:a}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subfloat[this is ...]{
\label{fig:ABC:a}
\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{ABC1.pdf}}
\hspace{0}
\subfloat[this is ...]{
\label{fig:ABC:b}
\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{ABC2.pdf}}\\[20pt]
\subfloat[...]{
\label{fig:ABC:c} 
\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{ABC3.pdf}}
\hspace{0}
\subfloat[...]{
\label{fig:ABC:d}
\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{ABC4.pdf}}
\caption{abcd}
\label{fig:ABC} %% label for entire figure
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

What should I add to display the number of the figure correctly?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please consider augmenting your code so that it becomes a compilable MWE (minimum working example) that generates the problem behavior you say you're encountering. The MWE should take care of loading all required latex packages -- and, ideally, *only* the required latex packages.

Comment: The modified code generates an error message, that the command `\subfloat` isn't recognized. I gather that this is a macro that's provided by the `subfig` package -- which, by the way, is not loaded in your example code. Given that the `subfig` package is quite obsolete, though, you should consider using the `subfigure` environment that's provided by the `subcaption` package. An example of how to use this environment is provided in the answer  I've given.

Comment: Thank you very much. but the exact code I put compiles with me, with typing 'return' once. and the pictures appear. Anyway, thank you very much for your information. I will try to use your suggested answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that requires only the capabilities provided by the `caption` and `subcaption` packages. Note the repeated use of the `subfigure` environment within a `figure` environment. To have the captions placed *below* the graphics, just move the subfigures' `\caption` commands to below the `\includegraphics` statements.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
\centering
\caption{First subfigure} \label{fig:ABC:a}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig1.pdf}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
\centering
\caption{Second subfigure}\label{fig:ABC:b}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig2.pdf}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Overall caption}
\label{fig:ABC}
\end{figure}

Here's a cross-reference to \autoref{fig:ABC}, and here's one to \autoref{fig:ABC:b}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. however, I remember I used 'subfloat' instead of 'subfigure' for a reason. Isn't there any difference?

Comment: I couldn't get your code to compile -- there's probably a package that you load but isn't listed in the example you provide. (That's also why people are usually encouraged to post a complete MWE rather than code fragments.) Please consider augmenting you code to make it a compilable MWE, and I'll take another look.

Comment: The figures now appear at the end of the document.. do you know why? thanks

Comment: Do you maybe have one or more `float` environments set up with `[h]` position specifier? Please see Frank Mittelbach's essay (at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/5001) for much more information on LaTeX's float positioning algorithms and, in particular, why it's usually not a good idea to use the `[h]` specifier. Alternatively, have you maybe loaded the `endfloat` package?

Comment: oh! thank you very much.. I probably wrote this in a hurry.. thank you for your information. I did solve the problem at the same time. I just deleted the 'float' package because of using your suggestion \subfigure instead of \subfloat